# Pyinstaller: FileNotFoundError: 'Lorem ipsum.txt' resource not found in 'jaraco.text'

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I tryed to convert a python script to a .exe, so I tried "pyinstaller --onefile script.py" and everything seems good and I get no errors.

When I try to execute the new .exe-file I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importlib\resources.py", line 131, in open_text
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI64082\\jaraco\\text\\Lorem ipsum.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    import irc.bot
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\irc\bot.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\irc\dict.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\jaraco\collections.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\jaraco\text\__init__.py", line 232, in <module>
  File "importlib\resources.py", line 169, in read_text
  File "importlib\resources.py", line 145, in open_text
FileNotFoundError: 'Lorem ipsum.txt' resource not found in 'jaraco.text'
[25068] Failed to execute script script
```

Have you any ideas what the problem is?
Sincerly Markus

PS: Sorry for my bad english i`m 16 years old and from Germany

Comment: can you show the code you are trying to bundle?

also there is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem that has been encountered by other PyInstaller users. The problem is that `jaraco.text` needed a hook file - a script which tells PyInstaller how to bundle packages properly. A [pull request](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/4632) was submitted to PyInstaller a few months back, and I finally merged it in about 2 weeks ago. This PR contained a hook for `jaraco.text` and fixes the issue you're having here.

To use this hook, you can install the development version of PyInstaller with:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
```

The current version in development is 4.0. We expect to release this in a few months.

Comment: Now 4.0 available via pip, so can be installed as usually `pip install pyinstaller`.